# Using "had" + past participle of verb in "simple past" style

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past

1. I had paid my bill.
2. I paid my bill.

I just want to make sure that the first sentence is correct. I understand that the second sentence is called `simple past`. If I use `had` as in the first sentence, is it still called `past perfect tense`? Or that is wrong English since there is no other action mentioned (e.g.: `I had paid my bill before going home`).

And with regards to the second sentence, is it correct to use `simple past` form like that even if no specific time was mentioned?

Thanks!

Comment: 'I had paid my bill.' is grammatically correct, but unacceptable without context.

Answer (score 1):

It's still past perfect tense. The action is "pay" here basically with bill as object and "I" as subject.

Yes to the last question as well.

And just a tip - in English, until your gut instinct tells you it's wrong and you feel wrong using the sentence, it's probably correct.